# How to get required options in magento to add a product in cart

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add a product to cart in Magento using Magento SOAP v1 API ,but am getting 
`Please specify the product required option(s).` error message.

The call happens like:

```
        $productArray[] = array(
            "product_id"=>"24",
            "qty"=>1
);
    $resultCartProductAdd = $client->call($session, "cart_product.add", array($shoppingCartId, $productArray));
```

I am unable to figure out how to find out what all options are needed to add a product to the cart. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check this product in magento admin panel. Either this product will have required custom option or this will be configurable product. Then you have specify option value also.

Comment: @RajivRanjan, let me put the question again, how to find if this product is configurable or requires custom options , as I have access only to Magento SOAP API, And if this product requires options, where will they be.

Comment: Before adding product to cart. Call catalog_productinfo to get product information and accordingly send option while adding product into cart. http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.info.html

Comment: @RajivRanjan , in the page that you pointed, it has an option called has_options  , the question is where to look for those options